# Can I get a car (with a loan in my name) back?

Tags: credit-card, car

My boyfriend doesn't have good credit. He's going to drive & pay the insurance, so I sold the car to him by paper, we didn't sign transfer of money ever. The credit is under my name. He's paying the amount.

If we broke up or he stops paying, can I take the car back again?

Comment: Have you already done this? Are you asking if it is a good idea to do this, or are asking how to get out of it if things go bad?

Comment: When you sold to him, was he recorded as the new owner? Is there an official record of the sale?

Comment: "so I sold to him buy paper, we didn't sign transfer of money ever" What does that mean?

Answer (score 4):

Your question is a bit confusing, you may wish to edit it to clarify the meaning.

> If we broke up or he stops paying, can I take the car back again?

No.

Just as if you sold me or the guy down the street your car you cannot just simply take it back.  Being someone's boyfriend does not grant special privileges to you or him.

Don't do this if you have not done so.  If you have try and get it undone.   It is unlikely that this is allowable as the bank will not simply allow you to transfer ownership if you have a loan.

In the future, use cash (not loans) to buy your cars.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little confused by your question to be honest. It sounds like you haven't sold it to him, but you have a verbal arrangement for him to use the car like it's his. I'm going to assume that's the case for this answer.

This is incredibly risky. If you've got the car on credit and he stops paying, or you guys break up... you will be liable for continuing to make payments!

**If the loan is in your name, it's your responsibility.**

Edited. The credit is yours. If he decides to stop paying, you're a little stuck.